# pygame, right goes down

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm using 2.7.10 on pygame and I can't understand why the right keeps going down instead of right. The left works perfect. I can't find any issues relating, so does anyone know what is wrong with this?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

White = (255,255,255)
Black = (0,0,0)
Red = (255,0,0)

pygame.display.set_caption('Test')

PyQuit = False

lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300

while not PyQuit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            PyQuit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x -= 10
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_y += 10


    GameDisplay.fill(White)
    pygame.draw.rect(GameDisplay, Black, [lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
lead_y += 10
```

Try:

```
lead_x += 10
```

Use `lead_x` for horizontal and `lead_y` for vertical.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it! =]

Answer (score 1):

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_y += 10'
```

You are making the lead_y += 10 when you should be adding 10 to the x coordinate

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lead_x += 10'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!